# how can I retrive data from a php controller in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to retrieve data from a php controller the following phrase that in place of product 1, 2, 3, etc and sellingcount no 380, 655, 275, etc but I don't know how to retrieve with jQuery.

```
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'graph_bar',
  data: [
    {device: 'Product1', sellingcount: 380},
    {device: 'Product2', sellingcount: 655},
    {device: 'Product3', sellingcount: 275},
    {device: 'Product4', sellingcount: 1571},
    {device: 'Product5', sellingcount: 655},
    {device: 'Product6', sellingcount: 2154},
    {device: 'Product7', sellingcount: 1144},
    {device: 'Product8', sellingcount: 2371},
    {device: 'Product9', sellingcount: 1471},
    {device: 'Product10', sellingcount: 1371}
  ],
  xkey: 'device',
  ykeys: ['geekbench'],
  labels: ['Geekbench'],
  barRatio: 0.4,
  barColors: ['#26B99A', '#34495E', '#ACADAC', '#3498DB'],
  xLabelAngle: 35,
  hideHover: 'auto',
  resize: true
});
```

Comment: i want to retrive data from a php controller the following phrase that in place of product1,2,3,etc(data from controller) and sellingcount no (data from controller) 380,655,275,etc but i don't know how to retrive data from a controller with jquery

Comment: Do you want to receive the data asynchronly or while building your view?

Answer (score 2):

You can change your code as following solution.

```
var data_graph_bar = [
                <?php 
                  if (!empty($graph)) {
                  foreach ($graph as $graph_val) { ?>
                  {device: "<?= $graph_val['device'] ?>", sellingcount: <?= $graph_val['sellingcount'] ?>},
                  <?php }
                  }  ?>
             ];


Morris.Bar({
  element: 'graph_bar',
  data: data_graph_bar,
  xkey: 'device',
  ykeys: ['geekbench'],
  labels: ['Geekbench'],
  barRatio: 0.4,
  barColors: ['#26B99A', '#34495E', '#ACADAC', '#3498DB'],
  xLabelAngle: 35,
  hideHover: 'auto',
  resize: true
});
```

**Note :** You can create Key value array in Controller side.

I hope this will helps you. Thanks!